# Find the locale in a file name

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How do I get the locale in the following XML file name in PowerShell?

```
xx12345(de-de,xxxx.54).xml
```

Try to find a better solution for the past hour but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like I wasn't using the substring method correctly.
$data = $file.name.Substring(9, 5)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex here unless the filename format is extremely rigid.  Here's a regex to extract the culture and locale:

```
'xx12345(de-de,xxxx.54).xml' -match '\(([^,]+),'
```

The info you want is in the automatic variable `$matches` in capture group 1 e.g.:

```
$matches[1]
```

Outputs:

```
de-de
```

Comment: If you want to be more specific you could use `\(([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}),` instead of `\(([^,]+),`.

Comment: That handles most but not all culture names e.g. `ca-ES-Valencia`.

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't aware such culture names even existed. In that case an expression `\(([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2,}(?:-[a-z]+)?),` might do.